# Transfer Learning - initialize weights from model trained using SGD to new network using Adam Optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a Multi-task(Classification and Regression tasks) Model with base Architecture of VGG-16 and i am using AdamOptimizer. I wanted to transfer the weights from VGG-16 Model trained on ImageNet dataset. But the Optimizer used here is Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD).

Is there a way i can transfer weights and biases from SGD to Adam?

Comment: What do you mean transfer your weights from SGD to Adam? , SGD and Adam are neural net optimizers, Your model weights are the result of your training, unless i misunderstood the question,

Comment: (Very very) unlikely. Adam has some kind of (per coordinate) memory/history/filter, which is depending on past iterations. While this informations is compressed into Adam's internals, it's not prepared within SGD. (**Edit** This addresses the transfer of the optimizer-state. Not the weights to learn.)

Comment: @sascha thanks.  These are tf variables created for one convolution layer using Adam(tensor_name:  conv2d/kernel, tensor_name:  conv2d/kernel/Adam, tensor_name:  conv2d/kernel/Adam_1). What does the second and third variables represent if we assume the first one is weights. Are these optimizer-state you are referring to. And can you look into this [link](http://www.cvc.uab.es/people/joans/slides_tensorflow/tensorflow_html/fine_tuning_vgg.html) where they have done exactly what i have asked for but i couldn't understand.

Comment: @sascha In general, is it okay to transfer weights from model trained on one optimizer to different optimizer?